# QTWeb upload file location

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I am implementing a web application for window using QTWeb. In web view, I use `<input type=file>`to upload an image from local disk to my web. I catch the action upload of this control and patch to my application. The problem is that the file path I got from webview is always C:\fake path..., so my application can not copy the exact file to the destination path. I wonder that there is anyway to get the "real" path.

Any help is very appreciated.

--
Tuan